# How to generate a java .property file of the latest svn revision number from command line?

Tags: svn, bash, properties, command-line-interface, revision

We are putting the svn revision number in the uploaded binary package, so the server and client know each other's revision number.

We choose to use java .property file because it is trivial to use.

The closest I can get is ( a bash file )

```
echo "svn.revision="

svnversion
```

But it consists of two lines. I need one line of `svn.revision=9353`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "-n" option on echo to suppress the newline:

```
echo -n "svn.revision="
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "svn.revision=`svnversion`"
```

Here's a working example for me:

```
$ echo "svn.revision=`svnversion`"
svn.revision=141
```

A variation of this is:

```
echo "svn.revision=$(svnversion)"
```

Comment: No problem - ennuikiller's answer works as well, though I'm curious what happened when you tried this?